# ломается программа при вводе существительных, которых нет в массиве

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cstring"
using namespace std;

char* spisok[][2] =
{
    "pilesos", "soset pil\n",
    "posudomoyka", "moet posudu\n",
    "stiralka", "stiraet\n",
    "holodilnik", "holodit\n"
};

int main()
{
    char keyword[100];
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter == 1)
    {
        cout << "enter a key-word: ";
        cin >> keyword;
        for (int i = 0; *spisok[i][0];i++)
            if (!strcmp(spisok[i][0], keyword))
            {
                cout << spisok[i][1] << endl;
                counter = 0;
                break;
            }
        if(counter == 1)
            cout << "no such keywords:( Try again." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* spisok[][2] =
{
    "pilesos", "soset pil\n",
    "posudomoyka", "moet posudu\n",
    "stiralka", "stiraet\n",
    "holodilnik", "holodit\n"
    "\0", "\0" // условие остановки цикла в for(int i = 0; *spisok[i][0]; i++)
};
```